# How to change the color of superscripts and subscripts in latex in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex, fonts, colors

Changing emacs themes, it seems that there is a variable that determines the color of the superscript `^` and subscript `_` symbols in latex math environments in org mode (in the source code not the exported document nor an org mode latex image preview).

How can I change the color of those symbols ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask emacs: with the cursor on such a subscript, do `M-x describe-char` to discover what face has been applied.  Now use `set-face-attribute` in your init to set your desired colour.

Comment: Thank you that worked. For those interested in an example : `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda() 
                           (set-face-attribute 'font-latex-script-char-face nil :foreground "red")
))`

Comment: The code in the previous comment was for org mode